# Adding multiple columns values from sql database in a php variable (without using an array name inhtml checkbox tag)

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

```
$queryStoreSecondaryInfo = $connection->query($sqlStoreSecondaryInfo);

if( $queryStoreSecondaryInfo ){
    echo "<br />Updated Secondary! <br />";
    $sqlUpdatedSecondaryInfo = " SELECT * FROM students_skills 
                                 WHERE ID='$_SESSION[ID]'  
                                 AND Email='$Email' ";
    $queryUpdatedSecondaryInfo = $connection->query($sqlUpdatedSecondaryInfo);
    while( $row = $queryUpdatedSecondaryInfo->fetch_assoc() ){
        $_SESSION["Landscaping"] = $row["Landscaping"];
        $_SESSION["Cleaning"] = $row["Cleaning"];
        $_SESSION["Delivery"] = $row["Delivery"];
        $_SESSION["Music"] = $row["Music"];
        $_SESSION["Maintenance"] = $row["Maintenance"];
        $_SESSION["Decoration"] = $row["Decoration"];
        $_SESSION["Painting"] = $row["Painting"];
        $_SESSION["PetCare"] = $row["PetCare"];
        $_SESSION["Tutoring"] = $row["Tutoring"];
        $_SESSION["Vehicles"] = $row["Vehicles"];
        $_SESSION["SnowRemoval"] = $row["SnowRemoval"];
        $_SESSION["Other"] = $row["Other"];

        foreach( $row as $skill => $value ){
            $postSkills=array();
            if( $value == "1" ){

                //if statement is true, add all column header names, 
                //ie. $skill values, together, and store in a variable, eg. $postSkills

            }
            echo $postSkills;
        }
    }
}
```

The SESSION values are coming from multiple checkboxes. I want to concat all names together, in a string, and store it as a session variable. 
I have seen other solutions and everywhere the response is to set the name of checkboxes as something like "name='array[]'. 
However, because of how my database is set up, I have to give each checkbox a unique name.
Is there anyway to concat all the column header names together, without creating a separate database to store the full list of skills together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make $postSkills an array, let it be string.  Store the skills in this by seperating them with '|' .

```
               $queryStoreSecondaryInfo = $connection->query($sqlStoreSecondaryInfo);

               if( $queryStoreSecondaryInfo ){
                   echo "<br />Updated Secondary! <br />";
                   $sqlUpdatedSecondaryInfo = " SELECT * FROM students_skills 
                                                WHERE ID='$_SESSION[ID]'  
                                                AND Email='$Email' ";
                   $queryUpdatedSecondaryInfo = $connection->query($sqlUpdatedSecondaryInfo);
                   while( $row = $queryUpdatedSecondaryInfo->fetch_assoc() ){
                       $_SESSION["Landscaping"] = $row["Landscaping"];
                       $_SESSION["Cleaning"] = $row["Cleaning"];
                       $_SESSION["Delivery"] = $row["Delivery"];
                       $_SESSION["Music"] = $row["Music"];
                       $_SESSION["Maintenance"] = $row["Maintenance"];
                       $_SESSION["Decoration"] = $row["Decoration"];
                       $_SESSION["Painting"] = $row["Painting"];
                       $_SESSION["PetCare"] = $row["PetCare"];
                       $_SESSION["Tutoring"] = $row["Tutoring"];
                       $_SESSION["Vehicles"] = $row["Vehicles"];
                       $_SESSION["SnowRemoval"] = $row["SnowRemoval"];
                       $_SESSION["Other"] = $row["Other"];

                       foreach( $row as $skill => $value ){
                           $postSkills="";
                           if( $value == "1" ){

                               //if statement is true, add all column header names, 
                               //ie. $skill values, together, and store in a variable, eg. $postSkills

                               $postSkills .= "$skill|";

                           }
                           if($postSkills!="") {
                               $postSkills = substr($postSkills,0,-1);
                           }
                           echo $postSkills;
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Now $postSkills will contain names of all the skills for which value is 1. Something like this -

```
$postSkills = "Landscaping|Cleaning|Decoration|Vehicles";
```

In order to set session variables from this, you will need to -

```
    $skillsArr = explode("|", $postSkills);

    foreach($skillsArr as $skill) {
        $_SESSION["$skill"] = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for tour answer. However, how would you set up an array to store the values as `$postSkills[0] => $_SESSION["Landscaping"]; $postSkills[1] => $_SESSION["Cleaning"]; ` and so on.......